# board realize redirect error with node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to go to the Details view after writing a new article. But if use res.reder and res.redirect together, get an error. So, what method can we use to move?

github : https://github.com/ChoYoungHo-web/watchingame_project

controller.js

```
export const getBoardCreate = (req, res) =>
  res.render("boardCreate", {
    homeName: "watchingame",
    pageName: "boardCreate",
    routers
  });
export const postBoardCreate = (req, res) => {
  try {
    let sql =
      "insert into board(folder,title,content, nicName,writeDate,views,comments) values(?,?,?,1,now(),0,0)";
    dbConnection.query(
      sql,
      [req.body.folder, req.body.title, req.body.content],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.render("boardCreate", {
            homeName: "watchingame",
            pageName: "boardCreate",
            routers,
            result
          });
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  res.redirect(/board${routers.boardDetail(?)});
};
```

Comment: You want to render `boardCreate` when the insert operation is successful, and redirect to `boardDetail` when it fails. Is that right?

Comment: yes, It is well stored in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of this code is: no matter the insert operation is successful or not, `res.redirect()` will always be executed (before the query result is returned), sending HTTP response to browser. After the insert operation is successful, `res.render()` is invoked, which try to send HTTP response to browser, again. This is not allowed in Node.js, as it will return 2 HTTP responses to 1 request.

In order to implement the requirement: render `boardCreate` when the insert operation is successful, and redirect to `boardDetail` when it fails, you need to move `res.redirect()` inside the `catch` block:

```
export const postBoardCreate = (req, res) => {
  try {
    let sql =
      "insert into board(folder,title,content, nicName,writeDate,views,comments) values(?,?,?,1,now(),0,0)";
    dbConnection.query(
      sql,
      [req.body.folder, req.body.title, req.body.content],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.redirect(/board${routers.boardDetail(?)});
        } else {
          res.render("boardCreate", {
            homeName: "watchingame",
            pageName: "boardCreate",
            routers,
            result
          });
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.redirect(/board${routers.boardDetail(?)});
  }
};
```